# Can't launch apps without internet connection - PlayOnLinux

Tags: playonlinux

I have a bunch of Windows programs on my Gallium OS installation (an Xubuntu-based linux distribution designed for Chromebooks) running on PlayOnLinux. When I have an internet connection the programs launch like normal. When I don't have internet connection the programs don't launch at all! Why this happens?

Log of foobar2000 : https://pastebin.com/3U0HcpJS

Comment: You need to provide more information. Which programs? Are there any error messages? Try to run the programs from the terminal and look messages that look like errors (`playonlinux file.exe`).

Comment: Ok I added the log of a music player called foobar2000 (great player btw) running on wine-2.0.1. I have another 3 apps that doesn't launch. I have them installed on my EXT4 formatted hard drive that has another 2 partitions. I managed this through symlinks. Keep in mind that ALL programs work fine with Internet connection. Also, when I open up the PlayOnLinux app it shows this error: PlayOnLinux website is unavailable. Please check your connection

Comment: Please split your one-line output by adding appropriate line breaks

Comment: https://pastebin.com/3U0HcpJS

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug on PlayOnLinux, version 4.2.10 doesn't have the bug so you can change to that by downloading it using `sudo apt install playonlinux`